# Unable to retrieve error description using Script component in VS 2022 integration Service project

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently working on an SSIS project and encountering an error that I am struggling to resolve.
I'm trying to retrieve error descriptions using the Script component with VS 2022. But the below error is getting

"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))" from C# code .

[image]

In 'error output data viewer' is also not showing an error code description. It is showing that " the component does not supply error code descriptions".

[image]

[image]

I am using/installed below tools:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2016
2. Visual Studio Professional 2022
3. SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2022
4. ODBC Driver for MS SQL

I'm new to the SSIS project. so could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and guide me through a beginner-friendly method to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.